# Nested (extended) promises seem to require a global variable

Tags: javascript, promise

I have written a library function `pRead(Path)`, which returns a JavaScript Promise to read a file on the local computer under an Apache server, using Ajax. I won't include the code for this, as it uses standard technology that is well-known to anyone who can give a good answer to this question.

I want to write a second library function, `pReadObj(Path)`, which will return a Promise to read a JSON file and provide its object value to asynchronous code. It should work like this:

```
pReadObj("test.json").then(then2).catch(pErr);
function then2(obj)
    {
    alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); // Shows the JSON obj
    } // then2
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
var globalPreviousResolve;

function pReadObj(Path) // Promise to read JSON from file
    {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
        {
        globalPreviousResolve=resolve;
        pRead(Path).then(pReadObj2).catch(pErr);
        });
    } // pReadObj

function pReadObj2(JSONStr)
    {
    globalPreviousResolve(JSON.parse(JSONStr));
    } // pReadObj2

function pTestDB() // Called from button
    {
    pReadObj("test.json").then(then2).catch(pErr);
    } // pTestDB
```

This works, but has a problem: using a global variable to hold the resolve callback is not only ugly, but it will clearly malfunction if two calls to pReadObj happen within a short period of time and the disk read takes a longer time than that.

The resolve function needs to be stored inside the Promise in some way, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [no need to explicitly create a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it); just return the one created by [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
function pReadObj(Path) {
  return pRead(Path).then(JSON.parse);
}
```

Comment: Wow. That works. So simple and elegant, the way arguments are handled implicitly. Promises are remarkable. Thanks, AuxTaco.